# Find system date-time format from SAP GUI and use it in frontend

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, sap-gui, sap-gateway

I have a SAPUI5 free-style app, where I display the date in a smart-table, in format DD/MM/YYYY.

However, in the frontend system in SAP GUI, my date format is MM-DD-YYYY. Is there a way to find this GUI date format and send it to the frontend app, so that I can modify the date format in my coding and display it accordingly?

I try to search it online. There are ways to find system time-zone, but no way to find date-format.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of OData to decouple and improve interoperability of both ends? If I understood it right, you'd like to display the date in the frontend app always in the format corresponding to SAP GUI which is quite a questionable choice.. What is the EDM type of that entity property?

Comment: Yes, you understood it right. My EDM type is "date", but the format is independent of GUI date format.

Comment: What's your locale? `sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLanguage()`

Comment: sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLanguage() is "EN"

Comment: @Vortex Are we talking about OData V2 or V4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAP table `USR01` contains the GUI dateformat in the field `DATFM`. It's only a Char1, but its domain lists you all the specific values.

You could then use a 'function import' in you OData service to get this value from the backend to your UI5 app.

But you might want to reconsider, since formatting the date should be handled by the browser locale instead a backend. But if your requirement forces you to do that, the way described above would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use already present function module: CLSE_SELECT_USR01?

Try using this:

```
FORM output.
CALL FUNCTION 'CLSE_SELECT_USR01'
EXPORTING     
USERNAME               = sy-uname
IMPORTING
DATE_FORMAT  =
  WRITE: / USERNAME               .
ENDFORM.
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will return the format date set for user in transaction SU01

```
select single ddtext
  from dd07t
  inner join usr01 on usr01~datfm = dd07t~domvalue_l
  into @data(lv_ddtext)
  where usr01~bname      = @sy-uname
    and dd07t~domname    = 'XUDATFM'
    and dd07t~ddlanguage = 'E'.
if sy-subrc is initial.
  find first occurrence of '(' in lv_ddtext match offset data(lv_offset).
  data(formatDate) = lv_ddtext(lv_offset).
endif.
```